# Template specialization in case of variadic template function

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have this function that is a a variadic template function:

```
template<uint C>
double foo(){
    double cpt = 1;
    for(uint i=0; i<10; i++){
        cpt += i*C; 
    }
    return cpt;
}

template<uint C1, uint C2, uint... CCs>
double foo(){
    double cpt = 1;
    for(uint i=0; i<10; i++){
        cpt += i*C1;    
    }
    return cpt + foo<C2, CCs...>();
}
```

And it works perfectly as expected but I think it is not the correct way to do what I want to do.
I tried to write something like that:

```
double foo(){
    return 0;
}

template<uint C1, uint... CCs>
double foo(){
    double cpt = 1;
    for(uint i=0; i<10; i++){
        cpt += i*C1;    
    }
    return cpt + foo<CCs...>();
}
```

But I have the error `no matching function for call foo() note: couldn't deduce template parameter C1`.
I also tried with a `template <typename T>` on top of the first `foo` function but I have the same error.

Does someone know why ?
I am using g++ 5.4 with -std=c++11 and -O3 flags.

Comment: `return cpt + f<CCs...>();` sure about that Viridya?

Comment: @gsamaras typo sorry

Comment: [OT]: You may get rid of the loop and directly do `return (45 * C1 + 1) + foo<C2, CCs...>();`

Comment: And `return foo<C1>() + foo<C2, CCs...>();` to avoid duplication of the formula.

Comment: Well, it was not about getting the smart code, it was about using variadic template function. The core of the function does not matter in fact, it was just an example :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final iteration will call `foo<>()`. It won't match the `double foo() { … }` because it is not a template function.

You can't fix it using

```
template <typename T>
double foo() {
    return 0;
}
```

because `T` cannot be deduced.

But you *can* provide a default value for `T` so that `foo<>()` becomes valid:

```
template <typename T = void>   // <---
double foo() {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Awesome. I did not even know we could provide a default value for `T`. Thanks !
I used to try something like:

template<typename T>
double foo <void>(){return 0;}

But it doesnt work.

Comment: @Viridya Template specialization doesn't work for functions. You'll need a class (`template <typename T> struct Foo ...`) for that.